# Does any one know how to search the annotations on MKMapView with UISearchBar?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, annotations, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I've searched for hours and I found Nothing

Also can anyone tell me if they know how to link a cell in grouped uiTableView to a certain DetailView and link a different cell to another DetailView?

Comment: What do you mean "search the annotations"? Your question isn't clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Map, Where would I put the Search Code and at if this is my annotations.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];


    // Central Alabama Chapter

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
    region.center.latitude = 33.45606;
    region.center.longitude = -86.83078;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 

    [mapView setDelegate:self];

    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
    ann.title = @"Central Alabama Chapter";
    ann.subtitle = @"721 Hillmoor Lane Homewood, Alabama 35209"; 
    ann.coordinate = region.center; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];


    // Walnut Ridge Fire Department

    MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
    region1.center.latitude = 36.11493;
    region1.center.longitude = -90.95695;
    region1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;



    DisplayMap *ann1 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
    ann1.title = @"Walnut Ridge Fire Department";
    ann1.subtitle = @"3217 Highway 67 # B, Walnut Ridge, AR"; 
    ann1.coordinate = region1.center; 
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
```

For the UITableView Grouped, where and how would i use that code if the code I have Looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *sectionOneArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mission Statement", @"Become a Member", @"Bible Ministries", @"FCFi on Facebook", @"Chapter Kit (PDF)", @"Corporate Members", @"FDIC Indianapolis", @"9/11/2001", nil];

    NSArray *sectionTwoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"About", @"Developer", nil];

    NSArray *websiteArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FCFi Website", nil];

    [listOfItems addObject:sectionOneArray];
    [listOfItems addObject:sectionTwoArray];
    [listOfItems addObject:websiteArray];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"More";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

search annotation-

It depends on by how you want to sear an annotation, if you want to search it by title then first get all the annotation by using annotation property of `MKMapView` as -

```
NSArray *arr = [mapView annotations];

for(int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)
{ 
     MKAnnotation *ann = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
     if([ann.title isEqualToString:[searchBar text]])
     {
         //do what you want to do after getting a annotation
     }
}
```

UITableView -

If you want to link on tap on cell then you can do it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for group table first check for indexPath.section and then check for indexPath.row .